# Batch moving a custom set of images with Ranger?

Tags: mv, move, ranger, batch-jobs

**This is a question for the [Ranger (file manager)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranger_(file_manager))**

Let's say that I have a directory with five files..

```
for i in $(seq 1 5); do touch "$i.jpg"; done;
mkdir subdir
```

How would I move `1.jpg`, and `4.jpg`, and `5.jpg`, into `subdir`?

I need something like a mark and move, or bulk move. Because these are images **I need to to be able to render the previews** in Ranger (already got that working), **before** I know which ones I want to move. For this reason I can not simply use `mv`. I need to interactively pick the batch.

Comment: Do you JUST want to move 1, 4 and 5? Or all you just created? What is this dependant on?

Comment: I explicitly said I'm using ranger which is a file-manager and I want be able to pick the files on the basis of the images previews.

Comment: Yep, dupe! @Sparhawk thanks for helping me find it.

Comment: No worries @EvanCarroll!