# How do I delete a single file without affecting the marked files in ranger?

Tags: delete, ranger, batch-jobs

As a follow up to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/484602/3285), how do I delete a single file without losing the selection that I've already got?

```
for i in $(seq 1 5); do touch "$i.jpg"; done;
mkdir subdir
```

Let's say you marked `1.jpg`, and `2.jpg`, but now you want to want to delete `3.jpg` before you continue and select `4.jpg` and move `{1,2,4}.jpg` into `./subdir`?

Answer (score 2):

To delete the highlighted file (without changing the marked files) you can add a keybinding to `~/.config/ranger/rc.conf`:

```
map xd delete %f
```

`%f` will expand to the highlighted file (delete without arguments deletes the marked file).